# trying to use AsyncTask to avoid NetworkOnSameThread errors

Tags: android, android-asynctask, lazy-loading

I am trying to implement an asynctask to run my network related task. but it doesnt seem to work, i keep getting nullpointerexception i am using lazy list.

```
public class Homepage extends ActionBarActivity{

    ListView list;
    LazyAdapter adapter;
    private static String url = "http://192.168.1.6/webservice/events.php";
    static final String TAG_IMG = "event_img";
    static final String TAG_SPONSER= "sponser";
    static final String TAG_TITLE= "title";
    static final String TAG_LOCATION="event_location";
    static final String TAG_TIME="event_time";
    static final String TAG_ENDTIME="event_endtime";
    static final String TAG_WHOINVITED="event_whoinvited";
    static final String TAG_MESSAGE="message";
    static final String TAG_DRESSCODE="event_dresscode";

    //private List<String> _list = null;
    //private String[] mStrings = null;
    ViewFlipper flippy;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> eventList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.homepage);


        //StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

        //StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);



        jsonThread jsonresult = new jsonThread();
        jsonresult.execute();
        adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, eventList);


        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(listener);


    }//end of onCreate\\\

    private class jsonThread extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONArray>{

        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);
            JSONArray jArray = null;
            JSONObject json;
            //_list = new ArrayList<String>();

            try {
                json = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                jArray = json.getJSONArray("posts");
                Log.d("jarray", "jarray post "+jArray);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return jArray;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            for(int u=0;u<result.length();u++){
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                JSONObject json_data;
                try {
                    json_data = result.getJSONObject(u);
                     String myevent_img = json_data.getString(TAG_IMG);
                     String sponser = json_data.getString(TAG_SPONSER);
                     String title = json_data.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                     String location = json_data.getString(TAG_LOCATION);
                     String time = json_data.getString(TAG_TIME);
                     String endtime = json_data.getString(TAG_ENDTIME);
                     String message = json_data.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                     String whoinvited = json_data.getString(TAG_WHOINVITED);
                     String dresscode = json_data.getString(TAG_DRESSCODE);

                     //_list.add(myevent_img);
                     map.put(TAG_SPONSER, sponser);
                     map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                     map.put(TAG_LOCATION, location);
                     map.put(TAG_TIME, time);
                     map.put(TAG_ENDTIME, endtime);
                     map.put(TAG_MESSAGE, message);
                     map.put(TAG_WHOINVITED, whoinvited);
                     map.put(TAG_DRESSCODE, dresscode);
                     map.put(TAG_IMG, myevent_img);
                    Log.d("jobj ", "event_img"+myevent_img);
                    Log.d("hashmap ", "sponser "+map.get("sponser").toString());
                    // need to put this to transfer the list to mstrings.
                    //mStrings=new String[_list.size()];
                    //mStrings = _list.toArray(mStrings);
                    eventList.add(map);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }   
    }

}
```

The code works just fine if i just put everything in `onCreate` and add

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

**//// edited**

```
public class Homepage extends ActionBarActivity{

    ListView list;
    LazyAdapter adapter;
    private static String url = "http://192.168.1.6/webservice/events.php";
    static final String TAG_IMG = "event_img";
    static final String TAG_SPONSER= "sponser";
    static final String TAG_TITLE= "title";
    static final String TAG_LOCATION="event_location";
    static final String TAG_TIME="event_time";
    static final String TAG_ENDTIME="event_endtime";
    static final String TAG_WHOINVITED="event_whoinvited";
    static final String TAG_MESSAGE="message";
    static final String TAG_DRESSCODE="event_dresscode";

    //private List<String> _list = null;
    //private String[] mStrings = null;
    ViewFlipper flippy;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> eventList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.homepage);



        jsonThread jsonresult = new jsonThread();
        jsonresult.execute();



        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(listener);


    }//end of onCreate\\\

    private class jsonThread extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>{

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);
            JSONArray jArray = null;
            JSONObject json;
            //_list = new ArrayList<String>();

            try {
                json = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                jArray = json.getJSONArray("posts");
                Log.d("jarray", "jarray post "+jArray);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for(int u=0;u<jArray.length();u++){
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                JSONObject json_data;
                try {
                    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(u);
                     String myevent_img = json_data.getString(TAG_IMG);
                     String sponser = json_data.getString(TAG_SPONSER);
                     String title = json_data.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                     String location = json_data.getString(TAG_LOCATION);
                     String time = json_data.getString(TAG_TIME);
                     String endtime = json_data.getString(TAG_ENDTIME);
                     String message = json_data.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                     String whoinvited = json_data.getString(TAG_WHOINVITED);
                     String dresscode = json_data.getString(TAG_DRESSCODE);

                     //_list.add(myevent_img);
                     map.put(TAG_SPONSER, sponser);
                     map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                     map.put(TAG_LOCATION, location);
                     map.put(TAG_TIME, time);
                     map.put(TAG_ENDTIME, endtime);
                     map.put(TAG_MESSAGE, message);
                     map.put(TAG_WHOINVITED, whoinvited);
                     map.put(TAG_DRESSCODE, dresscode);
                     map.put(TAG_IMG, myevent_img);
                    Log.d("jobj ", "event_img"+myevent_img);
                    Log.d("hashmap ", "sponser "+map.get("sponser").toString());
                    // need to put this to transfer the list to mstrings.
                    //mStrings=new String[_list.size()];
                    //mStrings = _list.toArray(mStrings);
                    eventList.add(map);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return eventList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
            adapter=new LazyAdapter(Homepage.this, eventList);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }




    }


}
```

**/////////LOGCAT\\\\**

```
04-05 22:24:34.204: W/dalvikvm(5680): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
04-05 22:24:34.524: E/AndroidRuntime(5680): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-05 22:24:34.524: E/AndroidRuntime(5680): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wordpress.yourhappening.happening/com.wordpress.yourhappening.happening.Homepage}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-05 22:24:34.524: E/AndroidRuntime(5680):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
04-05 22:24:34.524: E/AndroidRuntime(5680):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
04-05 22:24:34.524: E/AndroidRuntime(5680):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-05 22:24:34.524: E/AndroidRuntime(5680):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
04-05 22:24:34.524: E/AndroidRuntime(5680):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-05 22:24:34.524: E/AndroidRuntime(5680):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-05 22:24:34.524: E/AndroidRuntime(5680):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
04-05 22:24:34.524: E/AndroidRuntime(5680):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-05 22:24:34.524: E/AndroidRuntime(5680):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-05 22:24:34.524: E/AndroidRuntime(5680):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
04-05 22:24:34.524: E/AndroidRuntime(5680):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-05 22:24:34.524: E/AndroidRuntime(5680):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-05 22:24:34.524: E/AndroidRuntime(5680): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-05 22:24:34.524: E/AndroidRuntime(5680):     at com.wordpress.yourhappening.happening.Homepage.onCreate(Homepage.java:94)
04-05 22:24:34.524: E/AndroidRuntime(5680):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
04-05 22:24:34.524: E/AndroidRuntime(5680):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-05 22:24:34.524: E/AndroidRuntime(5680):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
04-05 22:24:34.524: E/AndroidRuntime(5680):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Post your stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`adapter` is `null` when you try to set it to your `ListView` in `onPostExecute()`.

Move

```
adapter=new LazyAdapter(Homepage.this, eventList);
```

to `onPostExecute()` before

```
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Also, your `for loop` there should probably be in `doInBackground()`

And don't use strict mode as you have pointed out that works. You can see why in the docs and tons of posts about it on SO.

**Edit after seeing logcat and comments**

Move

```
list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
```

from `onPostExecute()` to `onCreate()` before setting the `listener`. That's causing your `NPE`.

Comment: already tried that. if i put the `adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, eventList);` into onPostExecute, the only way it compiles is if i change this to Homepage.this. but that jus gives me a null pointer. And i tried putting my for loop into doInBackground but is still didnt work.

Comment: Ah, yes I missed that but have edited now. But that is how it would need to be since `eventList` isn't populated until the task finishes. I would run it that way and post the logcat from that so we can see what is `null`. It could be many things causing it but impossible to say without the stacktrace

Comment: What is the stacktrace everybody seems to be talking about? is that another word for logcat?

Comment: Yeah, the logcat output

Comment: i have posted the logcat and also i put the for loop in `doInBackground`. please have a look.

Comment: line 94 in my code is `list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()`

Comment: You have got to be kidding me. It worked!! i cant believe this has been killing me for the longest while. Thanks for the help and patience!